# Django - Managing page content in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, content-management-system, django-admin

I'm new to working with Django and am developing for a client who wants to be able to change page content in the Django Admin. They need to be able to change the html of the index page without editing the files on the server.

I know about flatfiles but I'm not sure that's completely what I'm after as I can't display stuff such as Django forms for example.

EDIT: Kind of like how a CMS works but without the users/group stuff and be able to use Django View modules such as forms.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the scope of what you're looking for is too huge to cover in this format. There's a number of ways this *could* be done, but they're all going to require some work and customization based on the client's needs.

Flatpages could work if you allow HTML content and make sure the content is rendered as "safe" in the template. This really only covers the "content" area of the site, though. It wouldn't be wise to use flatpages for an entire site template, including header, sidebar, footer, etc.

You could create editable areas. So, you actually create models for things like headers, sidebars, footers, and modules within those areas, and then just pull them into the template as needed. Then, the client is only editing pieces of the template instead of responsible for the whole HTML document.

Forms are going to be a challenge, because they require backend-processing that requires a connected view. The client won't be able to just arbitrarily drop in some form code and have a form. But, you could use a third-party service form forms and just embed them in the available content regions. Or, there's a couple of django apps that try to implement a type of "form builder" in the admin. That might somehow let the client add a form via something like the shortcodes used in Wordpress, but you'd likely have to lay down some infrastructure to make that work.

At a certain point, stuff like this reaches a point of diminishing returns, though. The only way to allow total customization of the template is to drop down into the actual physical file and make changes there. You can make certain things easier for the client, but ultimately, they either need to scale back their customization needs *or* deal with the fact that they'll have to work with the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am going to talk with the client and tell them that they need to deal with files.

Comment: How about creating editable areas in the template as you mentioned and then persisting the content for these in models and hence being able to edit them via the admin api as models can be edited there. Yes sounds like a big hack but should work, right?

Comment: Just so you know, I personally would not persist html in dbs just for easy editing. it's too much work and trouble for solving a problem that IMHO is not really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible at this time. Of course you can edit your models but templates, I think not.

Comment: Not *at all* what the author asked about. Read the question before answering.

Comment: @ChrisPratt he needs to be able to change the html of the admin pages. that's what the link talks about. am i missing something?

Comment: Thanks for commenting but what I'm wanting to do is be able to change web page content from the admin panel, not change the template of the admin panel.

Comment: Yep, you're missing something. He wants to manage the HTML of pages on the site *from* the admin, not change the admin.

Comment: Yeah, figured that now but I don't think the question made that very clear. Anyhow, I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would find out how much they need to change? If they plan a complete redesign every week then you're still looking for an answer. If they just need a dynamic front page then you can split it up into variables and let them edit sections of html. Much safer and less prone to breaking the html.

Comment: The site will be completely redesigned about every 1 and a half months. The site is a host of many different events and the whole design changes depending on the event.

Comment: A redesign is going to require file changes no matter how you cut it. This is a clear cut case of the client needing to accept a fact of life.